# How can I fix the wireless connection of my dual-boot 14.04 - windows 8.1 on my Asus laptop

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Here are the details:

```
########## wireless info START ##########
Report from: 15 Jan 2015 14:39 PHT +0800
Booted last: 15 Jan 2015 13:29 PHT +0800
Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000
##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6605]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

03:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b404 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:2006 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 
asus_wmi               24191  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
bcma                   52096  0 
wmi                    19177  1 asus_wmi
video                  19476  2 i915,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.5.2  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e23f:49ff:fecb:44ca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:584 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:174922 (174.9 KB)  TX bytes:69739 (69.7 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.5.100   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.5.2
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.5.100

    DNS:             202.69.165.10
    DNS:             202.69.191.10
    DNS:             202.124.193.3
    DNS:             210.4.2.61
    DNS:             210.4.2.62

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Manila (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     E41B811D88783DD5BC38565
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        00:A5:A6:57:59:DE:47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   10.101542] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x381f00)

########## wireless info END #####
```

#

Thanks and I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` will work for that wifi chip according to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110